# Create/edit subvi's in ev3-g (labview) developer mode

Tags: ev3-g

How can I create/edit subVIs in the ev3-g developer mode? I can open ev3-g blocks in the "LabVIEW" mode and Display subVI Details, but not edit or create subVIs itself. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by subVIs, and I doubt any other EV3 programmer knows either. Please clarify.

Comment: I understand your question but I dont know the answer. Have you solved it or found any resorses?